# Read data from Firebase is too Slow - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I'm working with Firebase to manage my app data.

Firebase seems to be great for managing data so far, but I have a problem when I need to read data from my database ..

To read my data from my Firebase database I perform this function

```
[[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Region"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        [_regionList addObject:snapshot.value[@"name"]];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
}];
```

The data is collected in the right way but the problem is that it seems to be a bit slow ...

To make you understand better ...

I have to view my data in a `UICollectionView` .. The problem is that there seems to be a bit 'of delay between viewing the `UICollectionView` and the data collected ... an example you can see it from the video I posted below ..

**[VIDEO](https://streamable.com/s/3seof/cngolm)**

Can you tell me where my mistake is? I seem to have done everything correctly but I do not understand this delay in reading the data

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _regionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _reference = [[DatabaseReference alloc] init];
    [self fetchRegion];
}

-(void)fetchRegion {
    [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Region"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        [_regionList addObject:snapshot.value[@"name"]];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    }];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.regionList.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ChooseRegionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.regionName.text = self.regionList[indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is loaded from the Firebase servers asynchronously. While this is great, because it means you're always looking at the latest data, it also means that it may take some time before the data is available.

Typical ways to make this delay (seem) shorter:

1. Load less data.

   The time it takes to load the data is based on 3 factors: your latency to the Firebase servers, the amount of data you load, and the bandwidth of the connection you load it over. Since you can't control the connection speed or latency of your users, the only factor you can control is the amount of data being loaded. Loading less data will make the delay shorter.
2. Start loading the data sooner

   You may be able to already start loading the data for the new view before the animation to the new view starts. That way the data is being loaded *during* the animations of the views, and the delay in the new view will be shorter.
3. Show a "please wait" animation

   Another solution is to show a "please wait" animation or banner to the user in the new view. This can be part of your static elements of the view, which you then replace with the actual data when that comes available.

There are definitely more tricks, but they get progressively more involved. If you're interested though:

- Enable disk peristence

  This is actually very simple, just [set a flag](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence). From that moment on, the Firebase client will initially load the data from the local disk cache and then synchronize it with updates from the server. But the implications of this approach can be a lot bigger than you may initialize realize, so I'd recommend only doing this if the steps above don't give satisfactory results.
- Keep a local snapshot

  A simple approach is to keep a screenshot of the last view contents in the local cache of your app and then show that straight away when the new view appears. While the user is scanning this calendar, the data is being loaded from the server and updated. This is in general a good approach if rendering data takes a non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your advice ... I noticed this delay because I was following a tutorial on youtube in swift .. this is the link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD582zfXlgo&index=4&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq ... as you can see he makes a query to get a list of all his users and their emails and the upload is very fast ... for this reason I do not understand where I'm wrong